# sending data from 1 data grid view to another data grid view in another form c#

Tags: c#, button, datagridview, click

The following method is used by me to send all rows from  a data grid view in a form(datagridview1 of form1) to another data grid view of another form(datagridview1 of form2) when a button is clicked.

```
     private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            f2.dataGridView1.DataSource = dt1;

            foreach (DataGridView row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                int n = f2.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
                foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dataGridView1.Columns)
                {
                    f2.dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[col.Index].Value = dataGridView1.Rows[row.Index].Cells[col.Index].Value.ToString();

}
            }

        }
```

But no data is sent to datagridview1 of form2! how can i correct this?

Comment: why not just copy from one datasource to the other?

Comment: @BugFinder how can i do that?

Comment: since you are not calling `f2.Show()` I will roughly assume that you have the wrong instance. Is your Form2 already open when you click the `button2` button?

Comment: @MongZhu not form2 is currently closed

Comment: @MongZhu after i put f2.show() an error occurs on the line "int n = f2.dataGridView1.Rows.Add();"

Comment: "an error occurs on the line" are you not telling us the error message on purpose?

Comment: @MongZhu on purmpose means?

Comment: what I mean is why don't you tell us the error message. There are a lot of different errors, each one has a different cause :) to find the problem one needs to understand the message

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the circumstances, I'd work with a data source, i.e. this way

VB.NET

```
Dim dt as New DataTable
dt = ds.Tables(0)

Me.DataGridView1.datasource = dt

Form2.DataGridView2.datasource = dt
```

C#

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables(0);

this.DataGridView1.datasource = dt;

Form2.DataGridView2.datasource = dt;
```

If you wanted to modify one of them independently, you need a second datatatable:

```
Dim dt2 as New DataTable
dt2 = dt.Copy()   ' copies datatable structure AND the data
Form2.DataGridView2.datasource = dt
```